# AJAX form submit error when sending form to twig in hook_preprocess_page

Tags: 8, ajax

I have a simple AJAX form that I can't submit when the form is passed from module to the template in hook_preprocess_page.  The same form works fine if sent from controller, it's just that the layout is complicated and I prefer to write the HTML part in the twig file and integrate the form where it fits best.

The form class:

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class SubmissionForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'mymodule_submission_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="submission-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['mail'] = array(
      '#title' => 'E-mail',
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['actions'] = array(
      '#type' => 'actions'
    );

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Submit',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array(
          'btn',
          'btn-success',
          'use-ajax-submit'
        ),
      ),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'wrapper' => 'submission-form-wrapper',
      )
    );

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }
}
```

The preprocess function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {    
    $vars['page']['submission_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\SubmissionForm');
  }
}
```

The error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse::setAttachments() must be of the type
>   array, null given, called in
>   /Volumes/Work/Git/myproject/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/AjaxRenderer.php
>   on line 56 in Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse->setAttachments() (line 37
>   of
>   /Volumes/Work/Git/myproject/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/AttachmentsTrait.php).

- it's a fresh Drupal 8.7.10
- devel and kint as contrib modules enabled
- core inline form errors enabled
- the form has only one required textfield and the submit button

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't identify the specific error but this does not seem like a good way to inject a form into a page. Why not implement a block in your module and add it to the page through the block admin?

Comment: @trudog I don't see any problem in the way you inject the form. Preprocess is fine, Could you update the code in question to contain the full form class

Comment: @Ziftman, I've updated the post with the whole form class.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong, since there's a very custom layout, the block admin page won't help me.

Comment: @trudog The code working fine, I can see the form added to the page, and If I fill it and submit it it disappears as expected, without any error. The logic of the form needs more work but that has nothing to do with the problem you describe

Comment: @Ziftman, did you inject the form through hook_preprocess_page?  No JS error in console and no watchdog php error + notice?

Comment: @Trudog Yes, I inject it in the same way, no errors at all

Comment: Thank you, @Ziftman.  This is frustrating.  I have no clue what might cause the error on my side.

Comment: What do you expect 'use-ajax-submit' is returning after the ajax request. I've never used it, but when I debug this the result is the rendered main content of the front page, which is in my case a view. Why not use the standard ajax pattern, which is an ajax callback returning the form in its wrapper?

Comment: @4k4, 'use-ajax-submit' uses by default validateForm and submitForm function in form controller.  I use it a lot, but until now only used it for forms displayed in modals--successfully.

I'll try the standard ajax pattern though--since every work around I've tried seems to come with a diferent bug.

@ Ziftman, just one thing: the form disappearing after submit is not right...  It should have remained there since there's no code to hide the form upon submit.  Also, try to submit with empty fields and you will see no error messages...

Answer (score 0):

The `#ajax['wrapper']` replaced with `#ajax['wrapper_selector']` that's why the form disappear see this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2821793):

Try with:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class SubmissionForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'mymodule_submission_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="submission-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['mail'] = [
      '#title'    => 'E-mail',
      '#type'     => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type'       => 'submit',
      '#value'      => 'Submit',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'btn',
          'btn-success',
          'use-ajax-submit',
        ],
      ],
      '#ajax'       => [
        // Change here the wrapper with wrapper_selector
        // 'wrapper' => 'submission-form',
        'wrapper_selector' => '#submission-form-wrapper',
      ],
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I would have to patch the core and don't want that for the moment.  I've followed what 4k4 suggested and managed to make it work using the standard ajax approach.  It seems that 'use-ajax-submit' doesn't work as expected in any situation.

Comment: You don't need to patch the core, i tested the code above with `'wrapper_selector' => '#submission-form-wrapper',` it works for me with no errors.

Comment: I did test without patching.  Got unexpected behaviour.  For example, required fields didn't get the error class and inline error message didn't show...